# Eclipse Issue - method checking

Tags: java, eclipse

You know how in Eclipse when you type a class name with a dot **"."** after, such as:

```
public void test() {
   TestClassTwo.
}
```

it would display a list of accessible methods to use from that class. 
Well for some reason my eclipse randomly stopped doing this, and I checked if my settings (Content Assist i think its called) and they all seem to be in order. So how come Eclipse stopped doing this? How do I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any compile errors in your class, especially fatal errors that would make Eclipse think this wasn't a valid Java class?  Does anything significant show up in the "Problems" view?

Comment: Nope! The problems view is empty. I have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: What happens when you press Ctrl+space after entering the period? Verify that the Java source file you're viewing is in a valid package and that package is in a valid source directory of the project.

Comment: While viewing the source file in question in the editor, is the icon on the tab a "J" in a box?  If you right-click in the editor and select "Show In..." and select "Package Explorer", does it list the source file within a package directory, or within a plain directory?

Comment: Pressing Control+SPACE brings up a little box saying "No default proposels", is this meant to happen or am I doing this wrong? haha

Comment: What if you create a new very simple project (unsure of your current project size) ?

Comment: Verify those other items I specified.  As busfault says, creating a dummy project and source file(s) to compare would be useful also.